# Lot of empty space between anchor tags

Tags: html, jsp, anchor

Hi am having a annoying issue.Look at the following code, In the code I have 2 links which appear based on conditions checked by the custom tag . The issue is when I see the HTML source of this page,the second anchor appears 700 lines(empty lines) after the first. Anyone pls help me solve this.Thanks in advance..

```
<a href="${contextPath}/rts/reports/listOfReports.do"> rts</a>
<s:userHasAccess functionId="<%=ReportsConstants.CFS_LOAD_PLANNING_FNCT_ID%>">             
<jsp:attribute name="yes">
<a href="${contextPath}/lprt/reports/listOfReports.do">lprt</a>
```

The custom tag does a privilege check and return true or false.

update:
HTML Source:

```
<a href="/ptp/rts/reports/listOfReports.do"> rts</a> //700 blank lines
<a href="/ptp/lprt/reports/listOfReports.do">lprt</a>
```

---

Comment: I'm having trouble replicating the problem: ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/8JW86.png) (This is the source I see in Chrome). What browser are you using?

Comment: You should move all your js into a script tag, it is exceedingly hard to read when you have your behavior and html mixed in together

Comment: as @Ilya Karnaukhov pointed out, we are having problems, reproducing  the described behaviour. Could you pls show us your html source as well as describe in detail what your custom tags do. thx

Comment: You might want to retag this question since it doesn't seem to be about the HTML and anchor directly but what is generating it. I assume JSP from the look of it but that is where your problem will come from. I don't know JSP but I'm guessing something (possibly your custom tag) is for some reason outputting a lot of whitespace. My guess would be including a large file whose contents is stripped out by the server but whose whitespace is remaining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked after adding the trim white space direcitve in the web.xml.

```
<jsp-property-group>     
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>     
<trim-directive-whitespaces>true</trim-directive-whitespaces>   
</jsp-property-group>
```